# Как устранить данный конфликт в Jquery коде?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.header-submenu__list  ul.ul-list > li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).children('.h-dropdown').addClass('active')
  })

  $('.h-dropdown__prev').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent('.h-dropdown').removeClass('active')
  })
```

Проблема в том что *.h-dropdown__prev* находится в *.header-submenu__list  ul.ul-list > li* и когда мне требуется убрать класс, он удаляет и потом заново добавляет потому что срабатывает опять первое события.
Как можно сделать что бы данного конфликта не было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте остановить распространение события

```
$('.h-dropdown__prev').on('click',function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).parent('.h-dropdown').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое